# Pass additional property to function binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to pass an additional property when binding the `value` to a function. Currently it does work as a one way binding (sets the value), but I'd also like to set the property on updating.

HTML code fragment:

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedProfile">
    <!-- ko foreach: Components -->
        <div class="row form-group">
            <!-- ko foreach: Variables -->
            <div class="row form-group">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.overridenValue(VariableId)"/>
                <!--I'd like something like: $root.overridenValue(value, VariableId)-->
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

JS code fragment:

```
self.overridenValue = function (variableId /*, value*/) {
    var variable = _.find(self.selectedProfile.Variables(), function(p) { return p.VariableId() === variableId() });
    //if value passed, then set the required property

    return variable ? variable.Value : null;
};
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you not binding to `$data.Value`? What do the `Variables` look like? Is `variable.Value` a `ko.observable`?

Comment: Because I have 2 different observable objects. Properties of one are used in the foreach loop, however one property value is filtered of another array, which is `overridenValue`

Comment: If value and VariableId are both observable properties on your viewModel you could just bind to a computed function that unwraps those properties instead of passing them as parameters.

Comment: `VariableId` is coming from one observable array and `value` is supposed to be set on another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

It is possible to pass the `$element.value` into the binding:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.overridenValue($element.value, VariableId)"/>
```

However thinking about it (and thanks to the comments), the approach I initially taken seems to be overly complicated for the purpose. A much cleaner one is to normalize the model instead.